# How can I change the overall direction of an table from RTL to LTR?

Tags: tables, xetex, languages

I'm creating my document in XeLaTeX. I type in persian with XePersian package. (a right to left language). By default it creates tables in right-to-left (RTL) direction. How can I change this, for my totally English tables to left-to-right (LTR)?

Comment: By default in what language does it do this?

Comment: I add some new information in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like surrounding the English text in the `xepersian` package's `latin` environment is the solution.

Disclaimer: I don't know this language, but I copied the text below from the first page of the `xepersian` documentation. I used the Nazli font because it is freely available through my Debian distribution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Nazli}

\begin{document}
‫این فقط یک مایش است‬ 

\begin{latin}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  One   & Two\\
  Three & Four\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{latin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For Debian users, Nazli comes in the package `fonts-farsiweb`.

Answer (score 2):

Although this topic  is old, many `LaTeX` users may come to this query to solve their similar problem.
The solution that `musarithmia` offered is good, but it doesn't work for tables filled by `Persian` characters. The problem is `Persian` characters within the `latin` environment will not be printed at all.
To essentially solve this problem, simply use the package `tabularray` and the environment `tblr` instead of tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Tahoma}

\begin{document}
‫این فقط یک آزمایش است‬ 

\begin{tblr}{ll}
یک   & Two \\
سه & Four\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```